# Golang Gin + Next.js аутентификация

Tags: golang, nextjs

Пишу учебное приложение с использованием фреймворка Gin (Golang) на бэкенде и Next.js на фронтенде. Хочу добавить в него аутентификацию и собственно приватные роуты. Для того, чтобы сделать приватные роуты необходимо проверять авторизованность пользователя как на клиентской стороне, то есть в (Next.js), так и на бэкенде. Для реализации аутентификации в Next.js решил использовать библиотеку next-auth и добавил туда GitHub как провайдер. Я понимаю, что приватные роуты можно реализовать с помощью next-auth на стороне клиента. Но мне же необходимо реализовать проверку и на бэкенде? Как это можно сделать?

Заранее спасибо

UPD: Появилась идея после получения сессии в next-auth конструировать jwt токен с параметрами, из сессии (например email). И уже на бэкенде с помощью секретного ключа проверять валидность jwt токена и наличия почты. И, таким образом будет проверяться аутентифицирован ли пользователь